# How to restart atd without affecting running jobs?

Tags: linux, batch, at

Does anyone know how to restart `atd` without affecting current running (`batch`) jobs?

I guess I could move the jobs out of the spool directory and wait for the current running jobs to finish, but I'm curious to hear.

Answer (score 5):

What OS are you using?

On Centos Redhat 5. I was able to restart atd with /etc/init.d/atd restart. My running jobs were unaffected and my scheduled jobs survived the restart:

```
$ date
Mon Dec 12 16:41:07 GMT 2011
```

As root:

```
# /etc/init.d/atd restart
```

They are still in the atq:

```
$ atq
2       2011-12-12 16:37 = bobby
1       2011-12-12 16:36 = bobby
4       2011-12-12 17:00 a bobby
```